# How to capture and save images from two USB cameras connected to a Raspberry Pi 3 simultaneously using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I'm looking to use a pair of top-bottom pair of stereo images taken by two USB cameras connected to a Raspberry Pi 3 for use on a drone. How do I save the images taken simultaneously in a folder on the pi? Here's what I did to get both the cameras working on two separate windows:

```
import cv2

frame0 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
frame1 = cv2.VideoCapture(3)
while 1:

   ret0, img0 = frame0.read()
   ret1, img00 = frame1.read()
   img1 = cv2.resize(img0,(1280,720))                          #360,240
   img2 = cv2.resize(img00,(1280,720))
   if (frame0):
       cv2.imshow('img1',img1)
   if (frame1):
       cv2.imshow('img2',img2)

   k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
   if k == 27:
      break

frame0.release()
frame1.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: have you tried with `cv2.imwrite` instead of `cv2.imshow` ? You can also use counter and a format to get the file name like `'img_{:04d}_cam{:d}.png'.format(img_counter, camera)` for example, `'img_{:04d}_cam{:d}.png'.format(42, 1)` gives  'img_0042_cam1.png'

Comment: @api55 Thanks, that worked perfectly. Any idea how to make it do that every 10 seconds so that I have a series of pictures from both cameras For example, img_0042_cam1.jpg, img_0043_cam2.jpg at the first second and img_0044_cam1.jpg and img_0045_cam2.jpg at the end of 10 seconds. Wouldn't want the same file to be over-written every 10 seconds

Comment: update: Just imported `time` and set number of frames and intervals and looped through to set up a timelapse.

Comment: I didn't have time to answer yesterday, is it solved? can you post the answer (or should I?)? so that anyone with the same problem can find the answer easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set of two images are saved every 7 seconds in the same directory as the .py file.

```
import cv2
import time

frames = 100
interval = 7

frame0 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
frame0.release()
frame0 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
frame1 = cv2.VideoCapture(3)
frame1.release()
frame1 = cv2.VideoCapture(3)
for i in range(frames):

   ret0, img0 = frame0.read()
   ret1, img00 = frame1.read()
   img1 = cv2.resize(img0,(1280,720))                          #360,240
   img2 = cv2.resize(img00,(1280,720))
   if (frame0):
       cv2.imwrite('./img_'+str(i).zfill(4)+'.jpg',img1)
   if (frame1):
       cv2.imwrite('./img2_'+str(i).zfill(4)+'.jpg',img2)

   time.sleep(interval)
   #k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
   #if k == 27:
    #  break

frame0.release()
frame1.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```